# Queue/stack/node class Implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack, queue

Below there are 3 short header files for `queue`, `stack`, and `node` implementation. I do understand that the `STL` has this capability(I am just doing it for practice). Please criticize the coding style, and things that you might thing i can/should do better. thank you. 
Note: since they are pretty short and `Node` class is used in the other two i posted all in here.

```
Node.h:
----------------------------------------------------
// Node.h
// 1-way linked node for use in simple integer Queue

#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H


class Node
{
public:
    Node();
    Node(int);

    int data;
    Node *next;
};

#endif
```

//-----------------------------//

```
 Node.cpp:
-----------------------------------------
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node()
{
    data = -1;
    next = nullptr;
}

Node::Node(int x)
{
    data = x;
    next = nullptr;
}
```

---

```
fmStack.h:
------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _FMSTACK_H
#define _FMSTACK_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"

namespace fm
{

    class fmStack
    {
        Node *top;

    public:

        fmStack();
        ~fmStack();

        void push(int);
        void pop();
        void dumpStack();

    };


}
#endif /* _FMSTACK_H */
```

//-------------------------------//

```
fmStack.cpp:
-----------------------------------------------
#include "fmStack.h"
using namespace fm;
//-------Private Methods----------

//-------Public Methods-----------
fmStack::fmStack()
{
    top = nullptr;
}

fmStack::~fmStack()
{
    top = nullptr;
}

void fmStack::push(int x)
{
    Node *node = new Node;

    node->data = x;
    node->next = nullptr;

    if (top != nullptr)
        node->next = top;

    top = node;
}

void fmStack::pop()
{
    Node *node;

    if (top == nullptr)
        std::cout << "Stack is empty" << std::endl;

    node = top;
    top = top->next;
    std::cout << "Poped from stack" << std::endl;
        delete node;


}

void fmStack::dumpStack()
{
    Node *node = top;
    if (top == nullptr)
        std::cout << "Stack is empty" << std::endl;

    while (node != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "data in stack at current position is" << node->data << std::endl;
        node = node->next;
    }

}
```

---

```
fmQueue.h:
```

---

```
#ifndef _FMQUEUE_H
#define _FMQUEUE_H


#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"

namespace fm
{
    class fmQueue
    {
        Node *_head, *_tail;
        void clearbuf();


    public:

        fmQueue();

        ~fmQueue();

        void deQueue(); // uses front to access data, or remove data
        void enQueue(int); // uses back to sort data, or add data
        void dumQueue();

        //int peek(); // get a copy of the front data without removing it

        bool isEmpty();

    };

}

#endif /* _FMQUEUE_H */
```

//---------------------------------//

```
fmQueue.cpp:
```

---

```
#include "fmQueue.h"

using namespace fm;

//---------Private Methods--------
void fmQueue::clearbuf()
{
    _head = _tail = nullptr;
}

//--------Public Methods----------

fmQueue::fmQueue()
{
    clearbuf();
}

fmQueue::~fmQueue()
{
    clearbuf();
}

bool fmQueue::isEmpty()
{
    if (_head == _tail && _head == nullptr)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


void fmQueue::enQueue(int data1)
{
    Node *tempNode = new Node;

    tempNode->next = nullptr;
    tempNode->data = data1;

    if (_head == nullptr)
    {
        _head = tempNode;
        _tail = tempNode;
    }


    else
    {
        _tail->next = tempNode;
    }

    _tail = tempNode;
}

void fmQueue::deQueue()
{
    Node *tempNode = new Node;

    if (_head == nullptr)
        std::printf("NOOOOP, THE QUEUE IS EMPTY");

    else
    {
        tempNode = _head;

        _head = _head->next;
        std::cout << "the data dequeued is: " << tempNode->data; //add a print statment to see which node was deleted

        delete tempNode;


    }

}

void fmQueue::dumQueue()
{
    Node *tempNode = new Node;

    if (tempNode)
        while (tempNode->next != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "Queue :" << tempNode->data;

            tempNode = tempNode->next;
        }
    else
        std::cout << "Nothing to show";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should realize, that your stack implementation leaks memory, if a non empty stack goes out of scope. In that case you have to recursively call delete on your nodes.

   To remedy this you should look into `std::unique_ptr` that handles the memory management for you.
2. Why does your stack doesnt have a function to retrieve the top node?
3. Is there any reason you defined int rather than making a template library?
4. dumpStack is a bad name, as dumping semantically involves throwing away. Maybe printStack?
5. Use correct constructors and initializer lists

   ```
   class Node
   {
       public:
       Node() {};
       Node(const int value)
          : data(value)   
       {}
       Node(const int value, Node* nextNode)
          : data(value)
          , next(nextNode)   
       {}

       int data = -1;
       Node *next = nullptr;
   };
   ```

   You can even simplify this itno a single one

   ```
   Node(const int value = -1, Node* nextNode = nullptr)
          : data(value)
          , next(nextNode)   
       {}

       int data;
       Node *next;
   };
   ```

   Then you push gets way easier

   ```
   void fmStack::push(int x)
   {
       Node *node = new Node(x, top);    
       top = node;
   }
   ```
6. You pop is seriously flawed. If the stack is empty, you still access top. In that case better throw a std::exception or at least do an early return

Comment: 1- I have to make a deconstruct method for my Node class. (I think)           2-I Believe in the pop method, node will be pointing to the top.

Comment: 4-I will change that                                                                                               5-I have never looked into creating constructor/initializer that way. I will do so                                                                                                                      6-I believe i have to wrap the staments in a else statment